# How to remove password and confirm password title from registration?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How to remove password and confirm password title from registration?
I can find the name of both is ['pass[pass1]'] & ['pass[pass2]']
i wrote below code in template i am able to remove other name and email label

```
enter code here

function mysubtheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 $form['account']['name']['#title']= t('');
    $form['account']['name']['#description']= t('');
    $form['account']['name']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('USER NAME'));
    $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = t('');
    $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = t('');
    $form['account']['mail']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('MAIL'));  
    $form['account']['conf_mail']['#title']= t('');
    $form['account']['conf_mail']['#description']= t('');
    $form['account']['conf_mail']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('CONFIRM EMAIL'));
    $form['account']['pass[pass1]']['#title'] = t('');
    $form['account']['pass[pass1]']['#description'] = t('');
    $form['account']['pass[pass1]']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('PASSWORD'));  
    $form['account']['pass[pass2]']['#title'] = t('');
    $form['account']['pass[pass2]']['#description'] = t('');
    $form['account']['pass[pass2]']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('CONFIRM PASSWORD'));  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the properties of the `pass1` and `pass2`, you need to add an additional `#process` handler that runs after FAPI's `form_process_password_confirm`, like so:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Allows modification of password fields in FAPI
 */
 function register_alter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   switch ($form_id) {
     case 'user_register_form':
       // Here we need to provide an extra #process handler to allow us to modify
       // the password element that FAPI expands.
       $form['account']['pass']['#process'] = array('form_process_password_confirm', 'register_alter_password_confirm');
       break;
   }
 }

 /**
 * Implementation of expand_password_confirm.
 */
 function register_alter_password_confirm($element) {
   $element['pass1']['#title'] = t("Password");
   $element['pass2']['#title'] = t("Repeat password");
   return $element;
 }
?>
```

This snippet is changing the name of Password's and Confirm password's title. If you want to remove it, just simply add `t("");`. If that's not working, you could also add a specific `<span>` into it, and giving a `display: none;` for it with CSS.

Hope that helps

*(NOTE: For Drupal 6 change `form_process_password_confirm` to `expand_password_confirm`)*

Comment: @ss153 Consider approving the answer by clicking on the check button near the answer above. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution in D8, try this https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/540340#comment-6576704

Answer (score 0):

To override the class property use the below attributes for password

```
/**
 * Implementation of expand_password_confirm.
 */
function register_alter_password_confirm($element) {
    $element['pass1']['#attributes'] ['class'][] = 'inputxlarge';
    $element['pass2']['#attributes'] ['class'][] = 'inputxlarge';
    return $element;
}
```